How to execute interrupts in embassy rust
I understand that my question is about 1 timer interrupt in specific, but I would prefer to learn where I can find out about this information on my own in the future.
I am using rust with embassy, with the stm32l0 chip, with a custom board. I am also verry new to rust (2 weeks now)
What i am trying to do in pseudo code is this:
repeat{
    set timer interrupt1 at 5 miliseconds;
    set timer interrupt2 at 10 miliseconds;
    wait 100 miliseconds;
}
interrupt1: set pin high
interrupt2: set pin low

This is relatively simple and could be done using other methods, it is more so to figure out how interupts work such that i can use them in a bigger project later on.
But i have been unable to find how to do this. This is the code I have so far:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use cortex_m::interrupt as cortex_interrupt;
use embassy_executor::Spawner;
use embassy_stm32::gpio::{Level, Output, Speed};
use embassy_time::Timer;
use {defmt_rtt as _, panic_probe as _};
use embassy_stm32::interrupt;

#[interrupt]
unsafe fn TIM2(){
    let pin = embassy_stm32::peripherals::PB0::steal();
    let mut pin2 = Output::new(pin, Level::High, Speed::Low);
    pin2.set_high();
}
#[interrupt]
unsafe fn TIM21(){
    let pin = embassy_stm32::peripherals::PB0::steal();
    let mut pin2 = Output::new(pin, Level::High, Speed::Low);
    pin2.set_low();
}

#[embassy_executor::main]
async fn main(_spawner: Spawner) {
    let p: embassy_stm32::Peripherals = embassy_stm32::init(Default::default());
    unsafe {cortex_interrupt::enable();}
    loop{
        Timer::after_millis(1000).await;
    
    }
}

the rust embedded book does not describe how you schedule / get interrupts to go off https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/start/interrupts.html (chapter 2.7) (they give general steps, but i was unable to figure out how to get it to work.)
There seems to have been this problem, but I don't think it is relevant here. https://github.com/embassy-rs/embassy/issues/2603 also using theire code does not work for me since "InterruptExecutor" gives 'unresolved import'. their UART4 also gives 'unresolved import' but I understand that this is hardware specific, but i would have expected InterruptExecutor to have been for all embassy, since it is in the embassy_executor crate.
or places like the embassy docummentation: https://docs.embassy.dev/embassy-stm32/git/stm32f107rb/interrupt/enum.Interrupt.html Don't provide the answer either.
This question is similar, but has no response Wait for ADC interrupts with Embedded Rust and Embassy on STM32 microcontroller
And chatgpt provides nothing that even close to compiles.

Is there a particular reason why you explicitly need an interrupt? The embassy way to acchieve what you want would be to spawn 2 tasks, one waiting the 5 seconds and the other waiting the 10 seconds and then doing their respective pin changes whenever the timer is done waiting

As far as I understand it:
async await does not do execute "at" 5 seconds, and "10" seconds. It executes "after" 5 and "after" 10,
If another task is bussy when the 5 seconds are over, and this other task takes for example 20 seconds then the timing would not be satisfied.
whereas an interrupt would satisfie the timings by interrupting the other task, to run the interrupt, and then allow the other task to continue.

I have considered adding "Timer::after_millis(0).await;" periodically in the longer task, but this would mean that every slightly longer task would have to do this which seems not ideal.

When you copied your code here there seems to have been a problem with \ being inserted, can you please fixup your code example and remove the extraneous backslashes? That might also be a good time to clean up the use statements, there seem to be many unused ones.

should be fixed now.

Found the answer (in the example folder of embassy)
This code gets the timers working:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::u8;
use defmt::*;
use embassy_executor::Spawner;
use embassy_time::Timer;
use {defmt_rtt as _, panic_probe as _};

use embassy_stm32::{gpio::{Output, Level, Speed}, interrupt, pac};
use embassy_stm32::time::hz;
use embassy_stm32::timer::low_level::{Timer as LLTimer, CountingMode};


#[interrupt]
fn TIM2() {
    // reset interrupt flag
    unsafe {
        let pin = embassy_stm32::peripherals::PB0::steal();
        let mut pin = Output::new(pin, Level::High, Speed::Low);
        pin.set_high();
    }
    pac::TIM2.sr().modify(|r| r.set_uif(false));
    info!("interrupt happens 2");
}
#[interrupt]
fn TIM21() {
    // reset interrupt flag
    unsafe {
        let pin = embassy_stm32::peripherals::PB0::steal();
        let mut pin = Output::new(pin, Level::High, Speed::Low);
        pin.set_low();
    }
    pac::TIM21.sr().modify(|r| r.set_uif(false));
    info!("interrupt happens 3");
}

#[embassy_executor::main]
async fn main(_spawner: Spawner) {
    let p: embassy_stm32::Peripherals =     embassy_stm32::init(Default::default());

    let timer21 = LLTimer::new(p.TIM21);
    timer21.set_counting_mode(CountingMode::EdgeAlignedUp);
    timer21.set_frequency(hz(2));
    timer21.start();
    timer21.set_autoreload_preload(true);
    timer21.enable_update_interrupt(true);
    unsafe { cortex_m::peripheral::NVIC::unmask(interrupt::TIM21) };

    let timer2 = LLTimer::new(p.TIM2);
    timer2.set_counting_mode(CountingMode::EdgeAlignedUp);
    timer2.set_frequency(hz(1));
    timer2.start();
    timer2.enable_update_interrupt(true);
    unsafe { cortex_m::peripheral::NVIC::unmask(interrupt::TIM2) };

    loop{
        Timer::after_millis(100).await;
    }
}

